# Best way to implement simple HTTP server push to C# client

Tags: c#, laravel, websocket

First of all, my apologies for the most likely inappropriate wording of the question. Not knowing exactly how to describe the problem I need to solve has been a major roadblock in my attempts to solve it.

I currently have a web server (Laravel) that needs to communicate with a SQL server in a different network, which only permits outgoing traffic. I made it work by having a C# daemon, running inside the SQL server's network, poll it for data and send it to the server through HTTP POST requests.

However, I now need the web server to communicate with the daemon. Something as simple as:

1. someone looks up a username on the web server
2. the server requests the daemon to look it up on the database
3. the daemon returns whatever information it found to the web server.

What I'm struggling with is finding the best way to do this.

All I need is for the server to be able to push requests to the daemon in real time. The daemon can reply through HTTP POST requests to the server, just like it is doing already. The best potential solution I have found is WebSockets, but it also sound like it might be overkill.

Am I missing something or are WebSockets indeed the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

[Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) is what I use to make HTTP requests to external APIs in Laravel.

Websockets are mostly used when the user has no control over the responses, for example, a chat window. But if you need to, for example, click a button and wait for the response Guzzle is enough.

Comment: My issue is that the daemon is in a network that blocks incoming connections, so I can't make it work as a server; it has to be the daemon establishing a connection, and I want the Laravel server to use that connection to communicate with the daemon… So Guzzle doesn't seem to be an option for me.